# New IP still banned using Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, http-status-code-403, amazon-vpc, elastic-ip

I am trying to make a web scraper but my ubuntu instance is getting banned. I think I am scraping the website a little too fast. I've slowed down the requests but I am still banned. To fix this I assigned the instance with a new IP by releasing my IP and reassigning it one with Elastic IP but it is still banned. How can I assign a new IP for my ubuntu instance to stop it from being banned? It does not seem like reassigning IPs with ElasticIP is the solution.

I dont want to terminate my instance as I would have to setup the new instance again. This instance is under a VPC as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you know for sure that the website owner is banning just specific IPs, then getting a new IP probably won't help.

There are plenty of websites that block the entire AWS IP range.

Comment: After some research I think this is what is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you stop an instance and start it again, you get a new ip address and the entire setup is intact. You wont have to set it up again